# Postgresql: More efficient way of joining tables based on multiple address fields

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, query-optimization

I have a table that lists two connected values, ID and TaxNumber(TIN) that looks somewhat like this:

`IDTINMap`

```
     ID    |     TIN
-------------------------
1234567890 |   654321
-------------------------
3456321467 |   986321
-------------------------
8764932312 |   245234
```

An ID can map to multiple TINs, and a TIN might map to multiple IDs, but there is a Unique constraint on the table for an ID, TIN pair.

This list isn't complete, and the table has about 8000 rows. I have another table, `IDListing` that contains metadata for about 9 million IDs including name, address, city, state, postalcode, and the ID.

What I'm trying to do is build an expanded ID - TIN map. Currently I'm doing this by first joining the `IDTINMap` table with `IDListing` on the ID field, which gives something that looks like this in a CTE that I'll call `Step1` right now:

```
     ID    |     TIN     |    Name    |    Address    |     City     |    State    |    Zip
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234567890 |   654321    | John Doe   | 123 Easy St   | Seattle      |     WA      |   65432
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3456321467 |   986321    | Tyler Toe  | 874 W 84th Ave| New York     |     NY      |   48392
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8764932312 |   245234    | Jane Poe   | 984 Oak Street|San Francisco |     CA      |   12345
```

Then I go through again and join the `IDListing` table again, joining `Step1` on address, city, state, zip, and name all being equal. I know I could do something more complicated like fuzzy matching, but for right now we're just looking at exact matches. In the join I preserve the ID in step 1 as 'ReferenceID', keep the TIN, and then have another column of all the matching IDs. I don't keep any of the address/city/state/zip info, just the three numbers.

Then I can go back and insert all the distinct pairs into a final table.

I've tried this with a query and it works and gives me the desired result. However the query is slower than to be desired. I'm used to joining on rows that I've indexed (like ID or TIN) but it's slow to join on all of the address fields. Is there a good way to improve this? Joining on each field individually is faster than joining on a CONCAT() of all the fields (This I have tried). I'm just wondering if there is another way I can optimize this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the final result a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html). Refresh it when you need to update the data (every night? every three hours?). Then use this view for your normal operations.

Comment: This is an option - but I'm not so much worried as just wondering if there's a way to improve the performance of the query itself when joining on all of these fields, rather than worried about how frequently we'll have to do it (as it is the query takes about 4 seconds to run)

Comment: You could index on (state, zip) -combination, maybe adding even address after those, this might help. Check `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see how it affects. Also, some years ago I used a postgres package to normalize U.S. addresses (makes "First North Street" -> "1st N St") or something like that, it will make more addresses match.